# Select range of cells in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, select, range

I was wondering if there is a way in pandas to select a range of cells, for example A3:AD43, as is done in excel.

I am using the below code to shade a range of cells with a heatmap. However, it does it on every single cell.

```
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("CSVFile.csv")
cm = sns.light_palette("red", as_cmap=True)
s = df.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm)
s.to_excel("ShadedFile.xlsx", index=False)
```

I tried adding a for loop, but that didn't work

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the Indexing Guide on pandas documentation? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Comment: Thanks for the link @r.ook. Yes, I tried that, however, when I write the excel file, I lose those columns and rows that were selected using df.iloc. If I try to insert them back in, then the styling pattern also gets applied to the insert columns and rows. I shall post my updated code for feedback.